# Scalding read multiple files from HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

How can I read all files from a directory on HDFS and process it using scalding. For the local filesystem I use the below

```
import com.twitter.scalding._
import com.twitter.scalding.JsonLine
import java.io._

class ParseJsonJob(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
  val fileList = new File(args("input")).listFiles
  val fields = ('device_guid
                ,'service_name
                ,'event_type
               )

  fileList.map {
    fileName =>
      JsonLine(fileName.toString, fields)
      .read
      .filter ('service_name) { name: String => name == "myservice" }
      .write(Tsv(args("output") + fileName.toString.split("/").last))
  }
}
```

That won't work with HDFS. Does TextLine or JsonLine read directories in addition to files?

Answer (score 0):

You would get a Hadoop FileSystem and use [FileSystem.liststatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) primitives to scan the HDFS directory, something like:

```
...
val hadoopConf= implicitly[Mode] match {
  case Hdfs(_, conf) => conf
}
val fs= FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
for(status <- fs.listStatus(new Path(args("input")))) {
  JsonLine(status.getPath.toString.toString, fields)
      .read
      .filter ('service_name) { name: String => name == "myservice" }
      .write(Tsv(args("output") + fileName.toString.split("/").last))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> import com.twitter.scalding._
>   import com.twitter.scalding.JsonLine
>   import java.io._
>
> class ParseJsonJob(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
>        val fields = ('device_guid,'service_name,'event_type)
>
> ```
>     JsonLine(args("input"), fields)
>     .read
>     .filter ('service_name) { name: String => name == "myservice" }
>     .write(Tsv(args("output") )   } }
> ```

This will work for you. Lemme know if it doesn't.